# ScrollView can host only one direct child exception

Tags: android

I want to add images to scrollview, there is code i tried to use:

```
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById( R.id.scrollView2);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( "PATH" ) );
        iv.setScaleType( ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE );
        sv.addView( sv );
```

I get this exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

So how i should add images to my scrollview ?

**Added code:**
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FF0000" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:background="#FFFF00" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/filesScrollerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And on the end Activity onCreate calling this method:

public void addImage(String path){

```
            LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout)findViewById( R.id.filesScrollerLayout);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( path ) ); 
        iv.setScaleType( ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE );
        sv.addView( sv ); 

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `sv.addView(sv)` looks wrong to me. Is there a reason for that statement?

Comment: I just want to add images to scrollView is there other solution beside this?

Comment: Change it to `sv.addView(iv)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this may help.. it tells so because ScrollView cannot hold more than 1 child.. it needs single child which hosts all other view..

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/child">
    <ImageView/>
    ...
    ...
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

in your case

```
LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout)findViewById( R.id.child);
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setImageDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( "PATH" ) );
        iv.setScaleType( ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE );
        child.addView( sv );
```

Comment: Now i get this:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.